# How can i filter Prepare Physical Count

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hello there i tried filtering the prepare physical count grid view but im not sure if im doing the correct process on this one. i added

```
#region UsrRemoveZero
[PXBool]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Remove Locations with Zero Qty")]

public bool? UsrRemoveZero { get; set; }
public abstract class usrRemoveZero : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrRemoveZero> { }
#endregion
```

i want to filter out book qty that dont have value > 0 but i am not successful this is where i am at so far.

```
protected virtual IEnumerable PreliminaryResultRecs()
{
    //PIGeneratorSettings filterrows = Base.GeneratorSettings.Current;
    //var filterrowsExt = PXCache<PIGeneratorSettings>.GetExtension<PIGeneratorSettingsExt>(filterrows);
    //foreach (PIPreliminaryResult row in Base.PreliminaryResultRecs.Select())
    //{
    //    if (filterrowsExt.UsrRemoveZero == true)
    //    {
    //        if (row.BookQty > 0)
    //            yield return row;
    //    }
    //}
    foreach (PIPreliminaryResult res in PXSelect<PIPreliminaryResult>.Select())
    {
        // Additional restriction goes here

            yield return res;
        
    }
}
```

but nothing is working on my end it just error out on the screen.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first expose the PXFilterable view in the extension.
I made a quick guide below that explains the pattern. I know there is other ways to do this but this works for me:

[How can I filter records for the Generate Recurring Entries (GL504000) screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011739/how-can-i-filter-records-for-the-generate-recurring-entries-gl504000-screen/67018750?noredirect=1#comment118534904_67018750)